# Elastic: Search on Must Not Empty and some other criteria

Tags: elasticsearch, dsl

Trying to do translate the below search. Essentially message1, message2 can have empty string values.  if search1Value or search2Value is empty string, i don't want any records returned for that part of the OR condition where there is an empty string.

```
message1 != "" and message1 = search1Value
OR 
message2 != "" and message2 = search2Value
```

so if example of available docs in index...

```
id, message1, message2
1, "", "abc"
2, "", ""
3, "def", ""
4, "", "ghi"
```

if searchValue1 is empty string, and searchValue2 is abc
i want to get back, only record 1.  Not record 1, 2, and 4.

Here is the setup

```
PUT test_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "message1": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "ignore_above": 20 
        }, 
        "message2": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "ignore_above": 20 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

data...

```
PUT test_index/_doc/1 
{
  "message1": "",
  "message2": "abc"
}

PUT test_index/_doc/2 
{
  "message1": "",
  "message2": ""
}

PUT test_index/_doc/3 
{
  "message1": "def",
  "message2": ""
}

PUT test_index/_doc/4 
{
  "message1": "",
  "message2": "ghi"
}
```

search ...

```
GET test_index/_search 
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "should": [{
        "bool": {
          "must": [{
            "bool": {
              "must_not": [{ 
                "term": { "message1" : "" }
              }]
            },
            "bool": {
              "must": [{
                "term": { "message1" : "" }
              }]
            }
          }]
        },
        "bool": {
          "must": [{
            "bool": {
              "must_not": [{ 
                "term": { "message2" : "" }
              }]
            },
            "bool": {
              "must": [{
                "term": { "message2" : "abc" }
              }]
            }
          }]
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

the above dsl doesn't work... can't seem to get it to do what i want.

Answer (score 0):

looks like i was doing it right.. but just had the brackets wrong..

```
GET test_index/_search 
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [{
              "bool": {
                "must_not": [{ 
                  "term": { "message1" : "" }
                }]
              }
            },
            {
              "bool": {
                "must": [{
                  "term": { "message1" : "" }
                }]
              }
            }]
          }
        },
        {
        "bool": {
          "must": [{
            "bool": {
              "must_not": [{ 
                "term": { "message2" : "" }
              }]
            }
          },
          {
            "bool": {
              "must": [{
                "term": { "message2" : "abc" }
              }]
            }
          }]
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}
```